# how to design the serializer in django rest framework for the Json response?

Tags: json, django, django-rest-framework

Hi am new to django rest framework.Currently am working on a thing which is contains a json response like this :

```
{
    "students": [
        {
            "first_name": <str: student first name>,
            "last_name": <str: student last name>,
            "unique_id": <str: student unique id>,
            "current_teachers": [
                {
                    "first_name": <str: teacher first name>,
                    "last_name": <str: teacher last name>
                },
                ...
            ]
        },
        ...more...
    ]
}
```

This is my serializer:

```
class StudentFilterSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Student
        fields = ("first_name", "last_name", "unique_id",)

class StudentFilterTeacherSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    first_name = serializers.CharField(source='teacher.first_name')
    last_name = serializers.CharField(source='teacher.last_name')

    class Meta:
        model = TeacherClass
        fields = ("teacher","first_name","last_name")

class FilterStudentsSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    students = StudentFilterSerializer(many=True)
    current_teachers = StudentFilterTeacherSerializer(many=True, required=False)
```

Now how to edit my serializer to achieve the json response.
Cause this is my current json structure:

```
serializer = FilterStudentsSerializer()
serializer.data
{'students': [], 'current_teachers': []}
```

Comment: Can you share your models and your view too please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be easier to provide correct answer if we could see how your models are implemented. Without knowing the fields connection, I will still try

Here's two kind of solutions:

**First:**

```
class StudentFilterTeacherSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    first_name = serializers.CharField(source='teacher.first_name')
    last_name = serializers.CharField(source='teacher.last_name')

    class Meta:
        model = TeacherClass
        fields = ("first_name","last_name")


class StudentFilterSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    current_teachers = SerializerMethodField(required=False)
    class Meta:
        model = Student
        fields = ("first_name", "last_name", "unique_id", "current_teachers")

    def current_teachers(self, student):
        # Get all teachers for this student
        # I don't know how your models are created but you'll get the idea
        # assuming you have "related_name" setup between student and teachers
        teachers = student.teachers.all()
        return StudentFilterTeacherSerializer(teachers, many=True).data
```

**and second** (probably not the one you want, still for your knowledge):

*Note: This will return all fields for teachers.*

```
class StudentFilterSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Student
        fields = ("first_name", "last_name", "unique_id",)
        # if you somehow have teachers field in 'student' model then you can also do
        depth = 1
```

Happy to help. 
Let me know if it works or you don't understand anything.